# Reading .txt file and seperating words and numbers into separate arrays

Tags: python

I've read the following expenses.txt file into Python

```
Rent: 40

Gas: 50

Food: 20

Clothing: 33

Car Payments: 133

Misc: 50
```

Then I want to create a pie chart reading the amounts and have the correct labels on the pie chart.

I thought the best way to do this would be to seperate the words and figures into seperate arrays, but I have no idea on how to seperate them into different arrays

Comment: Have a look here for some examples of creating pie charts https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_pie_charts.asp

Answer (score 0):

You want `str.split()`:

```py
data = {}
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip():
            continue # since you appear to have blank lines
        k, v = line.split(":")
        data[k.strip()] = float(v)
print(data)
```

### References

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0):

something like the below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

your_data = {
 'Rent': 40,
 'Gas': 50,
 'Food': 20} #TODO add more attributes


# Data to plot
labels = []
sizes = []

for x, y in your_data.items():
    labels.append(x)
    sizes.append(y)

# Plot
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]